# vagrant lamp configuration precise 64 by rove.io does not work?

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, chef-infra, vagrant

can anybody help me with configuring my vagrant lamp testing environment

I am using this [vagrant file](https://gist.github.com/strages/5436689/raw/13bc2dce3e0afd8f0ab28509cce742b488582c7e/Vagrantfile) and this [cheffile](https://gist.github.com/strages/5436689/raw/db95d1510c854a8b1a38d13db8dad724c4f553cf/Cheffile)

I got most of the settings inside the vagrant file from rove.io which is a Vagrant configuration generator plus also the chef file is from there.

When I vagrant up, it gives no errors so I would expect it to work by putting an index.html or index.php in my root which is then synced into my vagrant vm. 
However it gives me a 404 file not found error.

a little help would be appreciated :D still kinda new to this stuff

Comment: now i fixed it with some commands sudo sh -c 'echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/conf.d/name' and symlink the default file from sites-available to 000-default in sites-enabled + a restart of apache... However php does not seem to work now

Answer (score 0):

I think [this instruction](https://github.com/aderyabin/rove/issues/19#issuecomment-18670789) should help you.